# Plus / Minus buttons for input with javascript attached

Tags: javascript, jsp, e-commerce

I am looking to add plus and minus buttons to a quantity input on a checkout page. When the input is updated the javascript function is called an updates the total cost.

I have added the buttons and jquery which update the input box but I need help with the javascript function that updates the cost.

Here is the code for the buttons:

```
<button class='MIN'>-</button>
<input id='qty_<c:out value="${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}"/>' class="InputText" name='qty_<c:out value="${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}"/>' type="text" size="1" style="width:25px;" value='<c:out value="${quickCartOrderItemQuantity}"/>' style="text-align:center" onkeydown="JavaScript:setCurrentId('qty_<c:out value='${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}'/>'); CheckoutHelperJS.updateCartWait(this, this.value, '<c:out value='${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}'/>',event)" />
<button class='PLUS'>+</button>
```

Here is the jQuery for the buttons

```
 $(".PLUS, .MIN").click(function(){
       var itemVal = parseInt($(this).siblings(".InputText").val());
       if ($(this).hasClass('MIN'))
            itemVal--;      
       else
            itemVal++;
       $(this).siblings(".InputText").val(itemVal);
    });
```

Here is the code for the updateCartWait function:

```
updateCartWait:function(quantityBox, oldQuantity, orderItemId,event) {
    if(event.keyCode == dojo.keys.TAB)return;
    if(!this.isAjaxCheckOut()){ 
        return;
    }

    //Key pressed.. update the flag
    if(this.keyPressCount[orderItemId] == null && isNaN(this.keyPressCount[orderItemId])){
        this.keyPressCount[orderItemId] = 0;
    }
    this.keyPressCount[orderItemId] = parseInt(this.keyPressCount[orderItemId]) + 1;
    setTimeout(dojo.hitch(this,"checkInventoryAndUpdateCart",quantityBox,oldQuantity,orderItemId,this.keyPressCount[orderItemId]),this.updateWaitTimeOut);
}
```

And here is the checkInventoryAndUpdateCart

```
checkInventoryAndUpdateCart:function(quantityBox, oldQuantity, orderItemId, keyPressCountValue) {
    // Get quantities and status
    var inventoryStatusControl = dojo.byId("orderItem_inventoryStatus_" + orderItemId);
    var clearanceStatusControl = dojo.byId("orderItem_clearanceStatus_" + orderItemId);
    var availableQuantityControl = dojo.byId("orderItem_availableQuantity_" + orderItemId);
    var inventoryStatus = '';
    if (inventoryStatusControl && inventoryStatusControl.innerHTML != '') inventoryStatus = inventoryStatusControl.innerHTML;
    var clearanceStatus = 'false';
    if (clearanceStatusControl && clearanceStatusControl.innerHTML != '') clearanceStatus = clearanceStatusControl.innerHTML;
    var availableQuantity = 0;
    if (availableQuantityControl && availableQuantityControl.innerHTML != '') availableQuantity = parseInt(availableQuantityControl.innerHTML);
    var quantity = parseInt(quantityBox.value);

    if (inventoryStatus == 'Discontinued') {
        alert('This product is discontinued and can not be ordered.');
        return;
    }

    if (clearanceStatus == 'true') {
        if (availableQuantity < quantity) {
            this.showClearanceItemDialog(orderItemId, quantity, oldQuantity, availableQuantity, keyPressCountValue);
        } else {
            this.updateCart(quantity, orderItemId, keyPressCountValue);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (availableQuantity < quantity) {
        if (availableQuantity == 0) {
            this.showNoStockDialog(orderItemId, quantity, oldQuantity, availableQuantity, keyPressCountValue);
        } else {
            this.showInsufficientStockDialog(orderItemId, quantity, oldQuantity, availableQuantity, keyPressCountValue);
        }
    } else {
        this.updateCart(quantity, orderItemId, keyPressCountValue);
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have got it working by passing the values properly!

```
<button class='MIN' onclick="JavaScript:setCurrentId('qty_<c:out value='${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}'/>'); CheckoutHelperJS.updateCartWait(document.getElementById('qty_<c:out value="${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}"/>'), document.getElementById('qty_<c:out value="${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}"/>').value, '<c:out value='${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}'/>',event)">-</button>
<input id='qty_<c:out value="${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}"/>' class="InputText" name='qty_<c:out value="${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}"/>' type="text" size="1" style="width:25px;" value='<c:out value="${quickCartOrderItemQuantity}"/>' style="text-align:center" onkeydown="JavaScript:setCurrentId('qty_<c:out value='${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}'/>'); CheckoutHelperJS.updateCartWait(this, this.value, '<c:out value='${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}'/>',event)" />
<button class='PLUS' onclick="JavaScript:setCurrentId('qty_<c:out value='${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}'/>'); CheckoutHelperJS.updateCartWait(document.getElementById('qty_<c:out value="${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}"/>'), document.getElementById('qty_<c:out value="${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}"/>').value, '<c:out value='${orderItem.orderItemIdentifier.uniqueID}'/>',event)">+</button>
```